# marking a function dirty (specifying that caller should save all registers)

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a function `f()` that destroys all registers across the function call, except the stack pointer. How can I convey this to `gcc`, so that the caller will save all registers it wants to save, before calling `f()`?

EDIT:
I'm writing a coroutine handler, which needs to save state before switching to another coroutine and I'd like to save the minimum state possible. Say we have a function `yield()`, marked as "dirty", destroying everything except the stack pointer. This function will magically return after control returns to our coroutine, but it would be best if the caller, not the callee (since the caller knows best which registers it needs saved) would save all registers it needs to save before calling `yield()` and then restore them afterwards.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [clobber list](https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3)?

Comment: @RandomDavis Nope. The clobbered registers will be saved by the callee, not the caller. I want the caller to preserve (push/pop) all registers it wants to preserve. `f()` will only preserve the stack pointer.

Comment: In a comment? Why gcc needs to know that? If you want it to do it automatically, I believe there is no way for it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's because different calling conventions expect different registers to be preserved. To support them all, it would be easiest for the caller to save all registers it needs to before calling`f()`, or rather, I need a calling convention that only preserves the stack pointer and mark `f()` as such.

Comment: Looking at the [GCC Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), there is no such thing in the *Common* attributes, but I've found some options that might be useful in the *x86* attributes, such as `no_caller_saved_registers`. Which architecture are you targeting?

Comment: @AndréSassi I've seen this too, but it is the exact opposite of the one the OP is looking for, isn't it?

Comment: Mixing calling conventions is fundamentally a bad idea. It's not only an issue of preserving registers, but also putting parameters and return values in the right places.

Comment: Actually, no, it looks like the one needed: *The compiler generates proper function entry and exit sequences to save and restore any modified registers*.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I think it is the opposite, since the compiler would generate entry and exit *inside* the marked function (in my understating), but the marked function would be written in pure asm (not inline asm in C), so the compiler wouldn't touch it, the attribute will just indicate to the callee the convention. However, being the opposite implies that the default is what OP wants. If the function is inline asm in C with proper clobber list, then the compiler would handle it anyway in the place it better fits the architecture conventions.

Comment: *"(since the caller knows best which registers it needs saved)"* I disagree with that. Imagine that `A()` calls `B()` calls `C()` calls `yield()`. How is `C()` supposed to know what registers `A()` is using. Typically, there are scratch registers that all functions are allowed to trash. For all the other registers, the callee has to save/restore the registers it uses. That way, each function only needs to know what registers it needs, and doesn't need to know about the internals of any other function. So if `yield` expects to trash EVERYTHING, then `yield` needs to save everything.

Comment: C()'s call of yield() is invisible to A() and B(), since C() saves all registers it needs to to complete it's computation. If that means saving all registers, then OK.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that if A() is using register 42, but C() is not using register 42, then why would C() know to save register 42 before calling `yield()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and therefore should be avoided.

As a caller, I wouldn't expect to have to worry about register contents when calling a function. Furthermore, if you want the caller to handle it, why not handle it inside of f()? Not only will callers not need to be aware, you only need one implementation. With what you're proposing, each caller would need to handle saving/restoring the context, which is likely very error prone.

The basic solution could use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) to handle this in f(). Something like:

```
class ContextGuard {
  public:
    // Stores the current context
    ContextGuard() { ... }
    // Restores the current context
    ~ContextGuard() { ... }
  private:
     ...
};

...

void f() {
   ContextGuard contextGuard; // Saves the current context
   ... // Do stuff that mucks with the registers
} <-- contextGuard is destroyed here and the context is restored.
```

How to handle storing/restoring the context is another matter. [Boost.Context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/overview.html) may provide you with what you need.

One final point, beyond the stack pointer, there's some other intricacies with respect to registers as well. You'll need to take platform-specific function calling conventions into account here, possibly among other factors. If you are mucking with registers in such a way that you think they need to be restored, you're going to have to really understand the intricacies of all platforms you intend to run this code on.

Comment: because the caller knows best what it needs saved, the callee does not know. It can only save EVERYTHING.

Comment: @user1095108 Yes, that's the point.  You _should_ be saving anything, because otherwise there's no guarantee that you won't run into a one-in-a-million situation where losing data in one of the "unimportant" registers completely screws the caller over.

Comment: But the compiler knows everything. It does the saving, not the user. I don't see any astonishment. It knows which registers are used and which aren't.

Comment: That would only make sense if the caller knows precisely what f() is going to do. Otherwise, how could the caller know what needs to be saved?,What if f() changes later? The caller may only have saved contents mucked with by the previous version of f(), This all points to f() itself handling the context restoration.

Comment: "But the compiler knows everything." Not really. What if f() is in a different compilation unit and dynamically linked?

Comment: the caller allocates whatever registers it needs for it's use, all of them or just a few and saves them. It's all handled by the compiler, no need for the user of the function to know.

Comment: @Avram say, the caller just uses rax, rbx and rcx for it's computations, it knows this and saves them before calling f() and restores them after the call. It does not care about the other registers, it does not matter where f() resides or how it is linked.

Comment: I understand what you mean and in theory that could work. However, you should keep this encapsulated in f(). The primary pushback is not technical feasibility, but just good software development practices. Further, the compiler doesn't actually know everything. You (or a library you depend on) can embed customer asm and that *may* be problematic here. So, while you probably could put the onus on the caller, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the C functions [setjmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp) and [longjump](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/longjmp).

`setjmp` just does exactly that. It stores the context into the `jmp_buf` variable.

Afterwards, you can just call `longjump` to restore the context.

A sample implementation would be something like:

```
void f()
{
    jmp_buf my_jump_buffer;
    if (setjmp(my_jump_buffer) == 0) {
        // bla bla destroying any register you want (except sp)
        // if you need to change sp, you have to make the buffer a global var
        longjmp(my_jump_buffer, 1); // Will restore the context
    }
}
```

Comment: it unwinds the stack under MSVC :(, not a true `jmp`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with this:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
# if defined(i386) || defined(__i386) || defined(__i386__)
#  define clobber_all() asm volatile ("":::"eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx", "esi", "edi", "ebp", "cc");
# elif defined(__amd64__) || defined(__amd64) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__x86_64)
#  define clobber_all() asm volatile ("":::"rax", "rbx", "rcx", "rdx", "rsi", "rdi", "rbp", "r8", "r9", "r10", "r11", "r12", "r13", "r14", "r15", "cc");
# elif defined(__arm__)
#  define clobber_all() asm volatile ("":::"r0", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8", "r9", "r10", "r11", "r12", "lr", "cc");
# elif defined(__aarch64__)
#  define clobber_all() asm volatile ("":::"x0", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12", "x13", "x14", "x15", "x16", "x17", "x18", "x19", "x20", "x21", "x22", "x23", "x24", "x25", "x26", "x27", "x28", "x29", "x30", "cc");
# else
#  error "unsupported architecture"
# endif
#else
# error "unsupported compiler"
#endif
```

Clobbering `sp` shows a warning, which is why I did not include `sp`. You can include `clobber_all()` in your function prologue:

```
void f()
{
  clobber_all();
  // blah, blah, ...
}
```

which will inform the compiler, that the contents of (almost) all general-purpose registers have been destroyed.